# How to fix JSONDecodeError?

Tags: osmnx

I am new to OSMnx and followed the steps from the website (https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/10-building-footprints.ipynb) on how to make a "Street network + building footprints: square-mile visualizations" map.
All I did was change the location name to teutopolis and change the coordinates to the town I am trying to map out, but it kept giving me a JSONDecodeError output. I added an image of what I input and the error output that it gave me. Being new to coding, I am not sure what this all means as I tried to search for an answer but did not understand.
Any help on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Post a sample of your code to get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest version of OSMnx (0.8.1 as of this writing). This issue is documented [on GitHub](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/158) and was [fixed/released](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) two months ago.